# Observable arrays write by index KnockoutJS

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, frontend

I have trouble with write to observable array by specific index
JS

```
function AppViewModel()
{
this.curNumber = ko.observable("");
this.numbers = ko.observableArray([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
this.addNumber = function() { this.numbers[this.curNumber]++;}
}
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

HTML-page

```
<input type="number" data-bind="value: curNumber">
<button data-bind="click: addNumber">Add</button>
```

I expect that when i wrote "1" on input and click Add button, first indexed value will be incremented on one, but it doesn't work for me

Comment: I'm not familiar with knockout.js, but should the index in the `this.addNumber` function be `this.curNumber` instead of `curNumber`?

Comment: @jason-kennaly, thank you for fast response.  thank you for fast response. I fixed first post. But i still have this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
this.numbers[this.curNumber]++
```

Has several problems:

### Problem #1:

`this.curNumber` is an observable, you must call it as a function to get the value wrapped inside it.

### Problem #2

Even if you do that, it still won't work because the value you get from the DOM is a string, so you need to convert it to a number first.

```
var index = Number(this.curNumber());
```

### Problem #3

`this.numbers` is not an array, it's an `observableArray`. You can't index into it directly.

#### Option #1

Manually go into the array, then notify that value has changed (essentially [Kenneth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34845259))

```
this.numbers()[index]++;
this.numbers.valueHasMutated();
```

### Option #2

Splice!

The `splice` method is implemented on the `observableArray` and it behaves exactly like [the `splice` method on vanilla JS Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), plus it will automatically notify subscribers.

You can use it to place a new item on a specific index in this way:

```
array.splice(index, 1, newItem);
```

This means: take out one item from position `index` and place in it `newItem`

So in your case:

```
this.addNumber = function() {
    var index = Number(this.curNumber());
    var newValue = this.numbers()[index] + 1;
    this.numbers.splice(index, 1, newValue);
}
```

Check it out on jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/czfpbtbv/1

Answer (score 0):

```
function AppViewModel()
{
    this.curNumber = ko.observable();
    this.numbers = ko.observableArray([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
    this.addNumber = function() { 
        this.numbers()[this.curNumber()]++;
        this.numbers.valueHasMutated();
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

A `ko.observableArray` contains as a value a vanilla Javascript array so you need to extract the Javascript vanilla using `this.numbers()[index]`, note `()`, unwraps the ko.observableArray value and returns that value, a Javascript array.

In your code, you were trying to array index the ko.observableArray itself: `this.numbers[index]`

Finally, using @Kenneth's answer, you need to let KnockoutJs know that the ko.observableArray has mutated aka changed if your UI or other observables are to react to your `addNumber` call by calling `valueHasMutated` on `this.numbers`.

It might better to do use `subscribe` on the `curNumber` observable to listen for changes to `curNumber` and the `subscribe` function will just automatically fire your increment every time `curNumber` changes.

If it suits your needs, here is an implementation of using KnockoutJS `subscribe` and every time `curNumber` changes.

```
function AppViewModel()
{
    this.curNumber = ko.observable();
    this.numbers = ko.observableArray([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
    this.curNumber.subscribe(function(newValue) {
        this.numbers()[newValue]++;
        this.numbers.valueHasMutated();
    });
}
```

Now you do not need the additional step of calling `addNumber`.

**Below is just a test of valueHasMutated, I was double checking that extracting the Javascript array and updating an item in the array would be something KnockoutJs would not observe, and it is the case, you have to call valueHasMutated() or your array increment will go unnoticed by KnockoutJs**

```js
function AppViewModel()
{
  this.curNumber = ko.observable(0);
  this.numbers = ko.observableArray([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
  this.addNumber = function() { 
     resetUI();
     this.numbers()[this.curNumber()]++;
     this.numbers.valueHasMutated();
  }
  
  this.addNumberWithoutHasValueMutated = function() {
     resetUI();
     this.numbers()[this.curNumber()]++;
  }

  this.numbers.subscribe(function(newValue) {
     $('#divStatus').html("true");
  });
}

var viewModel = new AppViewModel(); 
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

function resetUI() {
  $('#divStatus').html("false");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>Array change is observed by Knockout:&nbsp;</label>
<span id="divStatus" style="color: red;">false</span>
<br />
<label>this.numbers() =</label>
<span data-bind="text: numbers()"></span>
<br />
<label>this.curNumber() =</label>
<input type="number" data-bind="value: curNumber" />
<br />
<br />
<button class="reset" data-bind="click: addNumber">Call AddNumber</button>

<br />
<br />
<button class="reset" data-bind="click: addNumberWithoutHasValueMutated">Call AddNumberWithoutHasValueMutated</button>
```

Comment: While this is valuable input, it doesn't really answer the question

Comment: Hi @Kenneth, My answer has the same function implementation as yours for the addNumber function, the difference is you are calling valueHasMutated, but ko.indexOf should be returning an observable, I am not sure you need to call valueHasMutated, the increment should be "observed" by knockout is my thinking

Comment: No, it doesn't. indexOf just returns the index of the first match. Whatever you do afterwards with that value is not observed by knockout. In fact, the way it's written doesn't even increment the value. It just gets you the index which you then increment and toss away.

Answer (score 0):

As Brian stated in his answer, the array is observable, but the values inside the array aren't. If you want to trigger an update, you have to do it manually by calling `valueHasMutated` on the observable:

```
function AppViewModel()
{
    this.curNumber = ko.observable("");
    this.numbers = ko.observableArray([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
    this.addNumber = function() { 
        var index = this.curNumber();
        var arr = this.numbers();
        arr[index] = arr[index] + 1;
        this.numbers.valueHasMutated(); // This tells knockout the value has changed
    }
}

ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, check fiddle: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/xwq6pgas/)

```
this.curNumber = ko.observable("");
this.numbers = ko.observableArray([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]);
this.addNumber = function() { 
            this.numbers()[parseInt(this.curNumber())] = this.numbers()[parseInt(this.curNumber())]+1;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this: this.numbers()[this.curNumber()]++; more readable than your answer, parseInt is fine, but not really needed either, curNumber shouldn't be initialized to a string like the OP's code anyways.

Comment: Also valueHasMutated() needs to be called as @Kenneth pointed out in his answer

Comment: Whatever you say. Didn't really have time to read  so much text for a simple problem. Just check my fiddle.  You don't need valueMutated.

Comment: Spoken just like someone who would write that long line of code for no reason.

Comment: And yes you do, if you want KnockoutJS to observe the change in the UI or other observables, kind of the point of KnockoutJS

Comment: My friend, why not just check my fiddle? You will see how it perfectly works without it.

Comment: Yes I know your Fiddle increments the array, but just add the following HTML to your Fiddle and you will see why you need to call valueHasMutated: <div data-bind="text: numbers()"></div>

Comment: I didn't notice were the author of the question asked this. What if he does `valueHasMutated` at some later point? Anyways if you want the update, the `valueHasMutated` is not always the best solution. If the array is big and so is the UI, you may prefer to replace one element with a new one with a `splice` method and trigger update of UI elements for that item only instead of triggering refresh of UI for the whole array as in the case of `valueHasMutated`.

Comment: LOL, keep digging, its all about Observables, its a design mistake for any observable property to not notify of changes, hasValueMutated notification is really implied, because its KnockoutJS, in regards to your large array well you said it was simple problem why are you talking about large arrays ;)

Comment: My point is that the method you just learnt may not be the best solution for all cases.